# Metric Document is too large in Azure ML Service

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to save metrics : loss, validation loss and mAP at every epoch during 100 and 50 epochs but at the end of the experiment I have this error: 
Run failed: RunHistory finalization failed: ServiceException: Code: 400 Message: (ValidationError) Metric Document is too large

I am using this code to save the metrics

```
run.log_list("loss", history.history["loss"])
run.log_list("val_loss", history.history["val_loss"])
run.log_list("val_mean_average_precision", history.history["val_mean_average_precision"])
```

I don't understand why trying to save only 3 metrics exceeds the limits of Azure ML Service.

Comment: you are not just logging three values but three lists of values. How long is each list?

Comment: Yes, 100 elements each

Comment: hm I could not find any public documentation for the limits of that so I would suggest you open an offical support ticket in the Azure portal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could break the run history list writes into smaller blocks like this:

```
run.log_list("loss", history.history["loss"][:N])
run.log_list("loss", history.history["loss"][N:])
```

Internally, the run history service concatenates the blocks with same metric name into a contiguous list.

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/resource-known-issues .